# find the point which has shortest sum of distance from all points?

Tags: geometry

I want to find a point in the Cartesian plane so that sum of distances from this point to all points in the plane be minimum.
For example we have the points: $(x_1,y_1),(x_2,y_2),(x_3,y_3), . . .(x_n,y_n)$. Now find a point - we call this $(X,Y)$ - so that:

$$\sum_{i=1}^n \sqrt {(x_i−X)^2+(y_i−Y)^2}$$ is minimal.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Note that for $n=2$ this is far from unique: any point on the segment between the two given points will have the same sum of distances.

Answer (score 2):

I think what you are looking for is the [Geometric median](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_median)

I'd recommend having a look at this [question at stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12934213/how-to-find-out-geometric-median)