# Find the minimum of sum

Tags: coordinate-systems, maxima-minima

Let $A(1, 1)$ and $B(3, 2)$ be two points. Find point $M(x, 0)$ so that the sum $AM + MB$ is minimum. After that, find the minimum of the sum.

In order for the sum to be minimum, I concluded that $x$ must lay between $1$ and $3$. I also calculated $AM$ and $MB$:

$$AM = \sqrt{x^2 - 2x + 2}$$
$$BM = \sqrt{x^2 - 6x + 13}$$

I don't now how to proceed from this point, so I would appreciate any help from you!

Thank you in advance!

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/613028/find-the-point-which-has-shortest-sum-of-distance-from-all-points

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider $B'(3,-2)$. Let $N$ be the intersection point of $x$-axis with $AB'$.

Then,
$$|AM|+|BM|=|AM|+|B'M|\ge |AN|+|B'N|$$

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\,{#1}\,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\Li}[1]{\,\mathrm{Li}_{#1}}
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
Let's $\ds{\quad x - 1 = \tan\pars{\alpha}\quad}$ and $\ds{\quad x - 3 = 2\tan\pars{\beta}\quad}$ such that
\begin{align}
\,\mathrm{D}\pars{x} & \equiv
\root{\pars{x - 1}^{2} + 1} + \root{\pars{x - 3}^{2} + 4} =
\sec\pars{\alpha} + 2\sec\pars{\beta}
\end{align}
$\ds{\alpha}$ and $\ds{\beta}$ are constrained by $\ds{2 = \pars{x - 1} - \pars{x - 3} = \tan\pars{\alpha} - 2\tan\pars{\beta}}$. So, we have to minimises
$\ds{\sec\pars{\alpha} + 2\sec\pars{\beta}}$ with the above constraining relation. Namely,
$$
\sec\pars{\alpha} + 2\sec\pars{\beta} -
\mu\bracks{\tan\pars{\alpha} - 2\tan\pars{\beta} - 2}
$$
$\ds{\mu}$ is a *Lagrange Multiplier*.
$$
\left.\begin{array}{rcrcl}
\ds{\sec\pars{\alpha}\tan\pars{\alpha}} & \ds{-} & \ds{\mu\sec^{2}\pars{\alpha}}
& \ds{=} & \ds{0}
\\[1mm]
\ds{2\sec\pars{\beta}\tan\pars{\beta}} & \ds{+} & \ds{2\mu\sec^{2}\pars{\beta}}
& \ds{=} & \ds{0}
\end{array}\right\rbrace
\quad\imp\quad
\left\lbrace\begin{array}{rcr}
\ds{\sin\pars{\alpha}} & \ds{=} & \ds{\mu}
\\[1mm]
\ds{\sin\pars{\beta}} & \ds{=} & \ds{-\mu}
\end{array}\right.
$$

---

Then, $\ds{\tan\pars{\alpha} = \pm\tan\pars{\beta}}$:

1. $\ds{\tan\pars{\alpha} = \tan\pars{\beta}\ \imp\ x - 1 = {x - 3 \over 2}\
   \imp\ x = -1\ \imp\ \,\mathrm{D}\pars{-1} = 3\root{5} \approx 6.7082}$.
2. $\ds{\tan\pars{\alpha} = -\tan\pars{\beta}\ \imp\ x - 1 =
   -\,{x - 3 \over 2}\ \imp\ x = {5 \over 3}\ \imp\ \,\mathrm{D}\pars{5 \over 3} = \root{13} \approx 3.6056}$.

   ---

   $$
   \color{#f00}{Solution:\quad\,\mathrm{M} = \pars{{5 \over 3},0}}\quad
   \mbox{with distance sum to }\ \,\mathrm{A}\ \mbox{and}\ \,\mathrm{B}\
   \mbox{equal to}\ \color{#f00}{\root{13}} \approx 3.6056.
   $$